# Random routes in node server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cron

I have created a server using the following:

```
function randomString(length) {
    var result = '';
    var chars = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    for (var i = length; i > 0; --i) 
        result += chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)];
    return result;
}

var cron = require('node-cron');
var rString = randomString(12);
cron.schedule('15,30,45 * * * * *', function(){
    rString = randomString(12);
    app.get("/"+rString, function(req, res){
        //Whatever you need goes here.
        res.send("Yo"); 
    });
    console.log("Your random route is: localhost:3000/"+rString);
});

//Tried this too
/*app.get("/"+rString, function(req, res){
        //Whatever you need goes here.
        res.send("Yo"); 
});*/
console.log("Your random route is: localhost:3000/"+rString);

app.get("*",function(req,res){
   res.send("Sorry no link found!"); 
});

app.listen(3000);
```

I'm trying to generate new routes for my server every 15 seconds. When I put the app.get inside cron job, it simply doesn't create a new route. And in the second place, the initial route is created but on updating the rString, it is not invalidating the initial route and creating the new one.

Comment: I don't have much in-depth knowledge of the process, but I think it sort of compiles our app.js and other route files when we start the server. I think that's why whenever we add a new route or change anything in the route files or app.js we need to restart our server ( using npm or forever etc.).

Comment: Instead of registering that much separate routes you can use a single route with some regular expression and for random Token you can use Redis In Memory database and in that route function you can check the token from Redis and process accordingly.

Comment: @JitendraKhatri I found a better way. I have posted the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found a way to do this.

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

function randomString(length) {
    var result = '';
    var chars = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    for (var i = length; i > 0; --i) 
        result += chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)];
    return result;
}

var cron = require('node-cron');
var rString = randomString(12);
cron.schedule('15,30,45 * * * * *', function(){
    rString = randomString(12);
    console.log("Your random route is: localhost:3000/"+rString);
});

console.log("Your random route is: localhost:3000/"+rString);
app.get("/:randomStr", function(req, res){
    if(req.params.randomStr === rString)
        res.send("Yo!")
    else
        res.send("Sorry no link found!");
});    
app.get("*",function(req,res){
    res.send("Sorry no link found!"); 
});

app.listen(3000);
```